# Get Area ID from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I need to get `Area ID` of the `work item` in **Azure DevOps** for creating custom `rules` in the process. Currently, I can only find `Area Path` of `work item` but for creating `rules` we need `Area ID`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Classification Nodes - Get Root Nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification-nodes/get-classification-nodes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) Rest API with `$depth` property to get all the area paths.

In the response you will get the Id for the Areas:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Additionally, you can add "Area ID" into the work item query columns:

[image]

Comment: Nice work aroud. But is a bit awkward that is impossible to see the IDs from Project Settings (where you can edit Area Path stuff)

Comment: in May 2023, I cannot see Area ID as a column option.

Comment: @G-E Yes, it disappeared... but you may enable 'New Board Hubs'  and find it again: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled